# Is RKE (from Rancher) production ready?

Tags: kubernetes, rke

All is in the title: Is RKE (from Rancher) production ready?

I tried to google it without success.

And is there any best practices to set up a production cluster with it?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why the vote down? If you have the answer, I'd like a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is rather hard to answer without knowing your acceptance criteria. What is production readiness from your point of view?

- High availability? Can be achived
- (Enterprise) Customer Support? Can be requested

Are you concerned about the conformance of the k8s deployment through rke? Check https://www.cncf.io/certification/software-conformance/ - Rancher is listed there.
Maybe give https://github.com/heptio/sonobuoy a try.

Cheers